# Menu not working in IE

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, menu

i have a site http://pvsmemorialhospital.com/

the top menu is not working correctly in IE

(**Activities and programs, academic programs)**

but it is working fine in Mozila and chrome.

plz help ...

### **UPDATE**

thank you guys it is now working correctly in IE 8, but it is not working in IE6

the problem was this, in the below code, there is no space between l(../images/activites.jpg) and left. when i give space between them it works fine in IE8

```
background:url(../images/activites.jpg)left top no-repeat;
```

In IE6, when we hover a menu item, it is showing an arrow.

PLZ HELP........

Comment: @paul it's a bit obvious isn't it ?

Comment: the jquery is used for autocomplete.js and its css. i removed both that and there is no error now. But still my menu is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Tue, 8 Mar 2011 10:23:03 UTC


Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 14
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://pvsmemorialhospital.com/scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js
```

you have an error there for some reason it cant find the jQuery variable. check that the jquery core file is included

**UPDATE**

background should be `url("../images/activites.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top transparent`

**not**

`url("../images/arrow.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top transparent`

The reason that is ... is done by js somewhere that gives it the wrong background picture

Comment: the jquery is used for autocomplete.js and its css. i removed both that and there is no error now. But still my menu is not working.

Comment: u have removed the core of jquery. but autocomplete depends on jquery core... so remove the script file `http://pvsmemorialhospital.com/scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js` as well as the core if you are deciding that

Comment: yes i removed jquery.autocomplete.js and its css. but still my menu is not working in IE

Comment: now the `<a>` tag give it a `display: block` in css so it takes the fills up the `li` tag

Comment: By the way using images for your menus is a bad, bad , bad idea as search engines do not pick up images how-ever you can put text into it, and then use the `text-indent` to hide the text so it is search engine friendly

Comment: hahaha @corbacho once his problem is solved, dont think people come back :)

Comment: @val my problem is solved partially, it is now working in IE8, but not working in IE6 (i updated the question). plz hlp...

Comment: if you are controlling the menu using css, look for the `a:hover` that has a background of arrow, if its a js then look for that arrow and replace them with the right image, if that dont work, f ie6 lol :) but im sure its either one or the other

Answer (score 0):

The error is that jQuery is not loaded. Why you have commented this line? `<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>-->`
Remove the `<!--  -->` part to see if it works.

Comment: You are right, that is **an** error, but it's not the problem with the menu.

Comment: @rotora actually that is the problem as jQuery variable is missing from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can see:

1. Your menu depends on Mootools, not jQuery.
2. You are not including jQuery, you need:

   `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
3. The error is probably stopping the execution of the rest of the scripts in IE and not in Firefox, but it seems to me that it will work fine once you include jQuery.